# "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" with angular.copy and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why do I get in to a digetst loop when I repeat over a cloned array?

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl1', function(MyService) {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.getData = MyService.getData;
    })
    .service('MyService', function () {
        var data = [
            {
             name: 'Adam',
                age: 12
            }, {
             name: 'Bob',
                age: 14
            }, {
             name: 'Caesar',
                age: 15
            }];
            
        this.getData = function () {
            // This is the offending line. If I remove the call to
            // angular.copy it works but in my real scenario I want to
            // modify the copy of `data` before returning it, without
            // affecting the original version. That's why I need to clone
            // it first.
            return angular.copy(data);
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl1 as $ctrl">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.getData()">
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `$ctrl.getData()`(binding) on view which does return an `data` array copy using `angular.copy`. So what happens is when digest cycle start it evaluates `$ctrl.getData()` and returns `data` copy, dues to reference change in `watcher`(binding) value. Angular re-runs digest cycle(it happens till all the binding gets stable). Again it tries to evaluate `$ctrl.getData()` value get and new copy of `data` array. So this process goes on as every time you are changing the reference of binding variable. Since after reaching to 10th operation it throws an error (by default angular digest cycle TTL = 10).

**How digest cycle?**

1. It goes through page collects all the bindings & put those expressions inside `$$watchers` array of `$scope`.
2. It starts initial digest cycle to evaluate of bindings, & update corresponding model value on page.
3. Digest cycle internally performs dirty checking, where it loop through all the `$$watchers` array & evaluate there bindings against `$scope`. Dirty checking meaning it check watcher expression `currently evaluated value` with its `old value`.
4. If any changes are found in dirty checking then again it re-run digest cycle from top to bottom(from $rootScope to all childs).
5. Until all the bindings gets stable this process happens.

> To fix this error you have to maintain two copies of variable in your
>   code.

Comment: But why is it calling `getData()` more than once? What am I doing that re-triggers the digest cycle?

Comment: Thats because , angular runs the digest twice . Once if the scope is not dirty, it will run the digest cycle for the second time to check it is clean & so on

Comment: @Tobbe check I explained why happens in that way.. do you have any doubts?

Comment: No here we have two binding `{{data.name}}` & `{{data.age}}`, but `ng-repeat` will also be putted inside watcher to evaluate its value each time if any value gets changes

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli No, its not true, It has 3 watchers, take a look at my updated answer as well. Thanks for your comments ;)

Comment: Can you explain step 3 more? Does it always call all bindings at least twice to have an "old" value and a "current" value?

Comment: Link on how it works , the digest cycle  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37377921/5173119

Comment: @PankajParkar , I think, since it is ng-repeat , there will be more than 3 watchers

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli totally it would have 7 watchers, but until `ng-repeat` isn't evaluate, it would have only two `watchers`, check plunkr for the same.. [plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/HwELZkO3adTa3gGu1ZRn?p=preview)

Comment: So the conclusion is once everything is compiled , only one watcher in watchersArray & watchers count is 7. Thanks for your effort

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli where do you find `$$watchersArray`? Isn't available anywhere in `$scope` object. where you found that thing?

Comment: @PankajParkar watchersArray I'm referring to is $$watchers in $scope

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli ohh.. I found that confusing.. please rename the same thing in your answer which you have linked..

Comment: @PankajParkar sure I will rename

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming because angular.copy() returns a new copy instance of the object. While angular is running the digest cycle , the scope is always dirty. The limit of digest iterations is 10. Thats why u are getting the digest limit reached error. Change your service to this, You are good to go.

```
this.getData = function () {
        return data;
    };
```

Comment: Yes. I know I get a new instance of the array (a clone/copy). What I don't understand is why Angular thinks it needs to re-run the digest cycle because of that.

Comment: And as I tried to explain in my comment in the code I can't just remove the call to `angular.copy`

Comment: For that u have to maintain two copies of data & return the second copy & modify it according to the requirement. But make sure u return the same object , not the new instance